# unity c# Animation property change sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good afternoon .

in animation property ( sprite ) , how to change a sprite of a certain frame in C #?
I tried to put an event by calling a function that takes the sprite rendering the object and puts in sprite field but does not change the run .
He runs that defined it in animation. I'm trying to change directly there but do not know how to do.

help please!!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've seen and researched, you can't to that currently.

The best workaround, one that i have done before and highly recommend, is to create something like a CustomAnimationClip script with an array of sprites and a timer to switch from each frame to the next. Then you can change the animation's sprites at any time by editing the array.

here is an example:

```
SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
public Sprite[] frames;

[SerializeField] int fps;
int currentFrame = 0;

float frameTime;
float frameTimer = 0;

void Awake()
{
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

void Start()
{
    frameTime = 1 / (float)fps;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = frames[0];
}

void Update()
{
    if (frameTimer < frameTime)
    {
        frameTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = frames[currentFrame];
        currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % (frames.Length);
        frameTimer = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it worked for you :) ? Thank you!